# Error: "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5114, 3409]"

Tags: python, data-analysis

I wish to follow the below steps:

1. Load data
2. Divide into label & feature sets
3. Normalize data
4. Divide into test & training sets
5. Implement oversampling (smote)

Is this the correct order of steps or am I doing anything wrong? I keep getting an error saying "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5114, 3409]".

This error occurs on line: X_train,Y_train = smote.fit_sample(X_train,Y_train)

```
#data loading
dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

#view data and check for null values
print(dataset.isnull().values.any())
print(dataset.shape)


# Dividing dataset into label and feature sets
X = dataset.drop('Bankrupt?', axis = 1) # Features
Y = dataset['Bankrupt?'] # Labels
print(type(X))
print(type(Y))
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

# Normalizing numerical features so that each feature has mean 0 and variance 1
feature_scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = feature_scaler.fit_transform(X)

# Dividing dataset into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split( X_scaled, Y, test_size = 0.5, random_state = 100)

print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
    
X = dataset.iloc[:,1:].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,0].values.reshape(-1, 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

# Implementing Oversampling to balance the dataset; 
print("Number of observations in each class before oversampling (training data): \n", pd.Series(Y_train).value_counts())

smote = SMOTE(random_state = 101)
X_train,Y_train = smote.fit_sample(X_train,Y_train)

print("Number of observations in each class after oversampling (training data): \n", pd.Series(Y_train).value_counts())
```

Comment: try using y_train instead of Y_train

Comment: That worked, thank you. Do you know why?

Comment: you are splitting your data twice. The first time you split the data the variable you use X_train and  Y_train. Second time  the varibale name you use are X_train, y_train. So when you tried fitting X_train and Y_train their dimension didn't match as X_train has the updated value we got from the second split but Y_train has value from the first split. Thats why we need to use y_train (the variable defined in second split). As python is case sensitive Y_train is not same as y_train